# php url values separated by slashes

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I am trying to use slashes in my url to navigate through my site. So far I can use the first value to call a class (a page), but when I use a second value (after a slash), the page becomes completely messed up and can't call my header.. Well, I hope you get what I mean and maybe help me out.

Here is my Config class, which takes care of the url navigation (mentioned above):
http://pastebin.com/38rmh9U1

The url[0] calls a class, but when I add another slash at the end of my url, the header class can't be called.

And this is what I have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Btw. I am not very strong in what should be in the .htaccess file, but I think this is about right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not clear on what is 'messed up' and what exactly happens to your header.

I assume your PHP is probably working okay. And your .htaccess is okay too.

I would guess your problem lays in HTML/CSS, where the included header stuff is probably trying to load css/javascript/images/stuff from the wrong directory.

Example, let's say I visit:

```
http://yoursite.com/home/someValue
```

And the page loads, and I get the HTML back. And let's say this HTML contains

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/scripts.js'></script>
```

Then your browser will try to get

```
http://yoursite.com/home/js/scripts.js
```

which is probably not the correct url for it.

To fix this, use some kind of baseurl, or always use urls based on the root (eg starting with a slash):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/scripts.js'></script>
```

Comment: I used a define() variable, containing the baseurl. It works perfect now. thanks for your help :)